# How to replicate an HTML button dropdown control using form controls

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an HTML5 form where the style of the controls look like this:

[image]

The pick list auto sizes to the width of the label, and the input field spans to fill the remaining space of the container div.

I can replicate this look and behavior using bootstrap v3.3.6 btn & dropdown-menu classes.  Since I need the data to post to a REST service, I'm trying to use the HTML5 select and bootstrap form-control class, but the outcome is less desirable:

[image]

I cannot find a way to add a label to the list, and the input field does not scale to the remainder of the div.

I've created a Bootply that demos both styles: http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/XWkY3FZYR5

Is there a way to form post the dropdown-menu selection?

**or**

Does anyone know how to achieve the same dropdown-menu look and feel with a HTML form select?